# Yii2 - Datatables filtering using column().search()

Tags: jquery, yii, datatables, yii2

I am using the Datatables in yii2..

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

// #column3_search is a <input type="text"> element
$('#column3_search').on( 'keyup', function () {
    table
        .columns( 3 )
        .search( this.value )
        .draw();
} );
```

with this code, it can search for a certain column.

is there an equivalent code for this using a dropdown `<select>` instead of using `<input type="text">`..

i wanted to use a dropdown type instead of the search box.

Sample Dropdown:

```
<select class="form-control-dropdown" name="month">
    <option id='January'>January</option>
    <option id='February'>February</option>
    <option id='March'>March</option>
    <option id='April'>April</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What could be the options inside `select`? Well you have **[something here to checkout](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/24959/dropdown-instead-of-search-box#Comment_69033)**

Comment: just the usual dropdown.. i have edited my question and added a sample dropdown..

Comment: Why not use built-in GridView widget?

Comment: the specifications needed for my project is to use datatables instead of using the gridview. :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this????

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control-dropdown" name="month" id="new_search">
    <option value='January'>January</option>
    <option value='February'>February</option>
    <option value='March'>March</option>
    <option value='April'>April</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();


$('#new_search').on( 'change', function () {
    table
        .columns( 3 )
        .search( this.value )
        .draw();
} );
```